# Создание графика с нуля

Tags: javascript

Подскажите где можно найти уроки по созданию подобных графиков **с нуля**?

**Без использования готовых библиотек!!!**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в любом учебнике, где рассматриваются графические инструменты

Comment: @Grundy, нигде такого не нашел

Comment: Подойдет svg или canvas

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, нужно на canvas, пытался найти какой нибудь учебник, но такой похоже не существует

Comment: Как нарисовать одну линию - знаете?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, знаю, хотелось бы найти описание как все полностью весь такой график с нуля создается

Comment: @Rickes417 допустим, отдельными линиями

Comment: А что именно в этом графике такого, что нужен отдельный учебник? По сути тут просто 18 прямых линий, из которых 14 это сетка и 4 - сам график. Если ты знаешь как нарисовать одну линию - ты уже можешь нарисовать этот график.

Comment: @Grundy и немного текста

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ну текст может не быть частью графика, которую нужно рисовать на canvas :) а просто дивы вокруг

Comment: @Grundy и линии бэкграунд градиентом :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, не уверен что канвасу можно background выставить :)

Comment: @Grundy https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/zYvbMvY?editors=0010

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, осталось еще оси таким же способом :-)

Comment: @Grundy можно линиями еще, а не точками

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, как-то мыльно выглядит :)